# TextField on Custom Cells

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am using custom cell inside `tableView`. In that custom cell, there is `label` and `textField`....this custom cell is being reused to display ten items. **I actually want to open a `datepicker` on one of the cell's text field** but I am not able to understand that how this work can be achieved?

Comment: Please learn about asking the question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please elaborate the question.

Comment: set tag to every textField and get when tap using same tag and further refer to [this](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=uitableview+custom+cell+objective+c+tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the text field tag and delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath method...
like..

```
cell.yourTextFieldName.tag = 1000;
cell.yourTextFieldName.delegate = self;
```

In .h file add the UITextFieldDelegate

Then in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate you can get the picker.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSInteger txtFldTag = textField.tag;
    if(txtFldTag == 1000){
//write the method to show picker.
return NO;
}
```

Comment: I guess, a key but missing point here would be to return NO, otherwise a keyboard appears.

Comment: yes you return the bool variable NO for not appears the keyboard

Comment: if you don't prevent appearance of the keyboard, it won't. If you do, it will.

Comment: this works..but the selector of bar button(Done) that I added to the date picker is not working now.       -(void)ShowDate
{
 
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
   NSDateFormatter* tripDateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [tripDateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
    _rTripDate = [tripDateFormatter1 stringFromDate:_tripDatePicker.date];
  
}

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create an instance of `UIDatePicker` and set it as `inputView` of one of your text fields. When the text field is tapped UIKit will animate appearance of the picker for you. In turn, you'll have to handle user's input and update the text field's text.